# Python Undefined variable 'rg'

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run this code, but get an error "name 'rg' is not defined". Could you please tell which library I can import rg from?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.floor(10*rg.random((3,4)))
print(a)
print(a.shape)
```

Comment: where have you defined `rg`?

Comment: What is `rg`? Don't know of any library named `rg`. Where did you get this code from? You probably meant `np`

Comment: I got this code from numpy documentation. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#shape-manipulation

Answer (score 4):

```py
import numpy as np
    
rg = np.random.default_rng(1)
    
a = np.floor(10 * rg.random((3, 4)))
print(a)
print(a.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the `rg.random()` to give a random integer between two numbers, you would use `random.randint(num1, num2)`.

So in your case, you would use this:

```
import numpy as np
import random

a = np.floor(10*random.randint((3,4)))
print(a)
print(a.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.floor(10*np.random.rand((3,4)))
print(a)
print(a.shape)
```

`np` is the alias you are assigning to `numpy`, not `ng`